# is it possible to send user entered keyword through anchor tag in php

Tags: php, html, button, search, anchor

i have a searchbox in my website like below:

```html
<div style="" class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="wrapda">
    <div class="searchda">
      <a href="https://google.com">
        <input type="text" class="searchTermda" placeholder="Search Image">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButtonda">
            <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
         </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

am trying to pass the user entered keyword in the input box to next page , is there anyway to do this using anchor tags, please help. thanks in advance

Comment: why not use <form></form>?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with some JS work. Use onchange event function and rewrite your url in anchor tag and pass whatever you want Like `https://www.google.com?input=yourvalue`

Comment: What do you want to achieve, Mention clearly.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond when i am using form, the searchbox is getting misaligned

Comment: @JohnDoe i just want to pass the user entered keyword to the next page in url

Comment: where will be the url defined ? can you eloborate

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat then it's just about changing css which, I think, is easier than using anchor?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond ok, how do i send through form, can u please show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using anchor tag, the more standard way is to use form.

```
<div style="" class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="wrapda">
    <div class="searchda">
      <form method="POST" action="your target url">
        <input type="text" name="searchInput" class="searchTermda" placeholder="Search Image">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButtonda">
            <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
         </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to specify the action attribute in the form tag which will be your target url.
You also have to specify the name attribute in the input tag.
This way your input will be sent to your target url.

Comment: bro, i used this but its not passing the value, here is my live URL https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/

Comment: It looks fine. If you use method="POST" your data will not be shown in the url but it's still there. You can get it by $_POST['name of input'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use form for this purpose.

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Image" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search Image" />
</form>
```